# How to webscrape data in R that is not available in page source?

Tags: html, r, web-scraping, rvest

I am attempting to scrape data in R for specific airports on flightradar, for example, https://www.flightradar24.com/data/airports/axa.

Specifically, I am wanting to scrape the contents of the arrivals and departures tables and store them in a dataframe. It seemed simple enough but the contents of the tables in not html page source.

I attempted to use a css selector on Chrome and identified the appropriate css selector using `rvest` functions, but it will not provide me the correct results. For example, in attempting to scrape the time using `tr td` as the css selector I tried:

`library(rvest)
webpage <- read_html("https://www.flightradar24.com/data/airports/axa")
time <- html_nodes(webpage, "tr td") %>% html_text()
head(time)`

> [1] " Loading..."
>   [2] "Sorry, we don't have any information about flights for this airport"
>   [3] " {{objFlight.flight.status.generic.eventTime.utc * 1000 || '' | date: timeFormat: timeZone}} {{objFlight.flight.time.scheduled.arrival * 1000 || '-' | date: timeFormat : timeZone}} {{objFlight.flight.identification.number.default}} {{objFlight.flight.airport.origin.position.region.city}} ({{objFlight.flight.airport.origin.code.iata}}) {{objFlight.flight.aircraft.model.code || '-'}}{{objFlight.flight.aircraft.registration}}{{objFlight.flight.airline.name}} -"
>   [4] "{{objFlight.flight.time.scheduled.arrival * 1000 || '-' | date: timeFormat : timeZone}}"
>   [5] " {{objFlight.flight.identification.number.default}}"
>   [6] "{{objFlight.flight.airport.origin.position.region.city}} ({{objFlight.flight.airport.origin.code.iata}})-"

Clearly the results are not as desired as it should be a list of the actual times of the flights. I am not sure where to go from here.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Open up Developer Tools in your browser. Refresh the page. You'll see _"Welcome to axa \n Please note that scraping or any other form of automatic data download is in violation of our Terms of Service (https://www.flightradar24.com/terms-and-conditions) and may result in lost access to Flightradar24. \n Please contact business@fr24.com should you wish to have access to our data services."_. Anyone that helps you may be put at risk for doing so (which is not cool). You've now got an email you can use to see if you can get legit access to the data services.

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out to me, I had not seen. I will make sure to contact their services before proceeding.

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to get the tables with the following code :

```
library(RSelenium)
library(XML)
shell('docker run -d -p 4445:4444 selenium/standalone-firefox')
remDr <- remoteDriver(remoteServerAddr = "localhost", port = 4445L, browserName = "firefox")
remDr$open()
remDr$navigate("https://www.flightradar24.com/data/airports/axa")
Sys.sleep(10)

page_Content <- remDr$getPageSource()[[1]]
readHTMLTable(page_Content)
```